# How do I get python 2.7 to print each element in a list on a separate line with a line number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

So here is my code right now:

```
lineNumber = 0
userPrompt = 0
userLines = list()

firstLine = raw_input("Please enter a line from a verse of your favorite song: ")

while True: 
    lineNumber += 1
    userPrompt = raw_input("would you like to enter more lines? ")   

    if userPrompt.lower() == "yes":
        userLines.append(raw_input("Please enter the next line in the verse: "))

    if userPrompt.lower() == "no":
        break
print("verse")
print("Line " +str(lineNumber) + ": " + firstLine)
print("\n" "Line " +str(lineNumber) + ": " + userLine)
```

Where Im having trouble is getting each element of the list to print on its own line with a line number on each as well. the second print statement is for the first input that happens outside of the while statement, and the third print statement is the one I am currently having trouble with.

The output should look like this:

verse

Line 1: #user input from the first raw input prompt

Line 2: #the first line from the list

Line 3: # the second line from the list

and so on...

Thanks for any help as I am lost on what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take your code and modify it a bit:

```
userLines = list()

firstLine = raw_input("Please enter a line from a verse of your favorite song: ")
userLines.append(firstLine)

while True: 
    userPrompt = raw_input("would you like to enter more lines? ")   

    if userPrompt.lower() == "yes":
        userLines.append(raw_input("Please enter the next line in the verse: "))

    if userPrompt.lower() == "no":
        break
```

So now we have a list of lines that are entered by the user stored in `userLines`

To print it out, all we have to do is this:

```
for index, line in enumerate(userLines):
     print('line={} says: {}'.format(index, line))
```

Enumerate is a python built-in (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate)). It essentially allows you to loop through a collection (a `set`, `list`, etc). In addition to looping over each item in the list (which is what a regular for-loop does), enumerate allows provides you the index within the collection that an item can be found at.

To put it simply:

```
for i in range(len(userLines)):
    index = i
    line = userLines[i]
    doStuff(index, line)
```

and

```
for index, line in enumerate(userLines):
    doStuff(index, line)
```

are equal

Hope that helps!

Comment: Then please consider clicking the tick-box next to the answer and accepting it. This will also resolve the question as having been answered. Have fun!

Comment: Just checked it off. If you dont mind, could you explain the for in loop and what each part does?

Comment: Edited the question to provide more context - hopefully that aught to make sense.

Comment: Instead of appending the firstLine to userLines list , you can print firstLine as such and while enumerating the list , pass start=2 as an argument in list i.e.  ::: for index, line in enumerate(userLines , start=2):